# Can't install drush8, having drush6

Tags: drush

I installed drush, and when I do "drush status" it says that my drush version is 6.6.0.

I want to have drush7 instead, so I downloaded it from github, and did following commands:

chmod +x drush.phar

sudo mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush

drush init

I get following error: the drush command init could not be found.

When I do drush status, it still says I have drush6 version... what do I need to do?

Comment: sudo composer global require drush/drush:7.1.0 doesn't work either

Comment: sudo composer global require drush/drush:8.x. This will work for both Drupal 7 and 8.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It says "your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Comment: That means you have something pre-existing that conflicts with the new stuff you're trying to install. You'll need to check your global composer.json and probably prune it manually

Comment: Yes, first delete your exitsting Drush 6. Then install Drush 8, not 7, just like you did.

Answer (score 0):

Can always install manually

```
# get drush latest 8 version from 
# https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases
# or any version that you want 
wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.16/drush.phar

# make it executable
chmod +x drush.phar

# move it to home directory or any other directory
mv drush.phar ~/drush

# go to that directory
cd ~

# find out the path to the directory
pwd
# the output would look similar to this
# /home/your_user

# edit the following file 
nano .bash_profile
# or in some systems
# nano .bashrc

# add this the end of the file
alias drush='/home/your_user/drush'

# use the alias you just setup
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**NOTES:** 
Above example works in ubuntu but should be similar on other distros

According to the [docs](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) drush 8 works with D8, D7 and D6 so no reason to install drush 7

If you want to call it with drush8 use following `alias drush8='/home/your_user/drush'` in `.bash_profile` file